# How to count the number of occurrences of an ID from a different table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, count

I'm using MS Access for this

I'm making an access database on UFC fights. I have a fightschedule table that has the IDs of each fighter for each fight and the winner of the fights. I'm trying to make a query that lists every fighter that fought and lists how many wins each one had.

This is an example of my fightSchedule table

```
    ID  Fighter1    Fighter2    Weight Class            Date    Winner
    A   205         215         Light Heavyweight   8/14/2013   205
    B   206         212         Welterweight        8/15/2013   212
    C   207         218         Middleweight        8/14/2013   207
    D   208         209         Heavyweight         8/14/2013   209
```

So for for example I want a query that would look something like this:

```
    Fighter        # of Wins
    205             1
    206             0
    207             1
    208             0
    209             1
    212             1
    215             0
    218             0
```

I don't know much about what would go into doing this at all. I know how to use the count function but no idea how to use it like I want in this example.

I found this on W3 Schools but I don't know if this is the right one to use or how to use it.

```
SELECT column_name, COUNT(column_name)
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY column_name
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not that difficult. You need to build up the query in baby steps:

1) Select all fighters that ever fought at least one fight, but don't count those more than once that fought several fights:

```
select distinct fighter1 from
(
    select fighter1 from fightSchedule 
    union select fighter2 from fightSchedule 
)
```

2) Select the number of wins for the fighters that actually won:
*(this is basically the query that you found on W3Schools)*

```
select winner, count(winner) as Wins
from fightSchedule
group by winner
```

3) Combine the first two queries:

- We need the list of fighters from the first query, and the list of wins from the second query, so we need to `JOIN` the two queries.
- Not every fighter won one of his fights, so not all fighters from the first query are present in the second query.
- That's why we need to do a `LEFT JOIN`, meaning that we select all rows from the first query and only those that match from the second query
  *(the standard `INNER JOIN` would have filtered out all rows from the first query that are missing in the second query)*

In MS Access, there are two ways how to do the second query:

It's easier if you save the first two queries as named queries in Access.
Then you can query them like tables in the third query:

```
select fighter1 as Fighter, nz(wincount,0) as Wins
from qryFighters
    left join qryWinners
    on qryFighters.fighter1 = qryWinners.winner
```

*(it's a matter of taste to prefix the query names with stuff like `qry`. I just did it in this example to emphasize that they're queries, not "regular" tables)*

If you don't want to save the queries as named Access queries, you can do it as well all in one big SQL statement, although it's more complex and is likely to confuse you if you're not experienced in SQL:

```
select fighter1 as Fighter, nz(wincount,0) as Wins
from
(
    select distinct fighter1 from
    (
        select fighter1 from fightSchedule 
        union select fighter2 from fightSchedule 
    )
) as fighters
left join
(
    select winner, count(winner) as wincount
    from fightSchedule
    group by winner
) as winners
on fighters.fighter1 = winners.winner
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally what you want to do is to unpivot columns into rows. There're several ways to do this in different RDBMS.
Since you haven't specified you RDBMS, I'll start with very general way - to unpivot columns with [union all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28SQL%29). I think this query will work in any RDBMS:

```
select
   Fighter,
   sum(Wins) as Wins
from
(
  select
      Fighter1 as Fighter,
      case when Fighter1 = Winner then 1 else 0 end as Wins
  from fightSchedule
  union all
  select
      Fighter2 as Fighter,
      case when Fighter2 = Winner then 1 else 0 end as Wins
  from fightSchedule
) as a
group by Fighter
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce3b8/1)

On the other hand, for SQL Server you can use [outer apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
select
    C.Fighter,
    sum(C.Wins) as Wins
from fightSchedule
    outer apply (
        select Fighter1, case when Fighter1 = Winner then 1 else 0 end
        union all
        select Fighter2, case when Fighter2 = Winner then 1 else 0 end
    ) as C(Fighter, Wins)
group by C.Fighter
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm using microsoft access and I'm not sure how to use it. I put it in my Builder and it is telling me the syntax is incorrect. I have mediocre experience with access and very little with SQL code so I'm not sure what I should edit